# Rename and delete Room Database

Tags: android, database, android-room

I am wondering how to rename or delete a Room Database which was instantiated by following code:

```
AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
```

Should I expect a `database-name.db` file in `getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()`, which I could then rename or delete? Would this approach be safe?

My current workaround would be to use only one database with multiple tables, emulating multiple databases. I am not sure if this approach scales very well though.

I could not find any answers to this question in the [documention](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room). I am not asking how to rename or delete columns or rows.

Comment: Path to database can be obtained using `getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("database-name.db")`.  Documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)

Comment: I figured out that you can delete the database using `context.deleteDatabase("database-name")`. My question regarding the renaming-part still remains, as such method is not provided by `Context`

Answer (score 1):

A way to rename a Room database file while preserving existing data:

```kotlin
fun provideDatabase(appContext: Context): AppDatabase {
    renameOldDatabaseFilesIfExist(appContext)
    return Room
        .databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
        .build()
}

private fun renameOldDatabaseFilesIfExist(appContext: Context) {
    if (!appContext.getDatabasePath(OLD_DATABASE_NAME).exists()) {
        return
    }
    // Room generates additional files with postfixes like '-wal', '-shm',
    // if you don't rename these files, the existing data will be lost.
    val dbFileNames = appContext.databaseList().filter { it.startsWith(OLD_DATABASE_NAME) }

    for (dbFileName in dbFileNames) {
        val databaseFile = appContext.getDatabasePath(dbFileName)
        if (databaseFile.exists()) {
            val newFileName = dbFileName.replace(OLD_DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_NAME)
            databaseFile.renameTo(File(databaseFile.parent, newFileName))
        }
    }
}

const val OLD_DATABASE_NAME = "old-database.db"
const val DATABASE_NAME = "new-database.db"
```

Answer (score -1):

To rename a room database you can do the following when getting your database instance :

```
//Kotlin
fun getDatabase(context: Context) : YourRoomDbClass {
   return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this){
       val dbFile = context.applicationContext.getDatabasePath("your_old_db_name.db")
       if(dbFile.exists()) dbFile.renameTo(File(dbFile.path + "your_new_db_name.db"))
       val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, YourRoomDbClass::class.java, "your_new_db_name.db")
                          .build()
       INSTANCE = instance
       instance
   }
}
```

Comment: You have to use `context.applicationContext.getDatabasePath("your_new_db_name.db")` when calling `renameTo()`